# remove some routes from sails + swagger autogenation

Tags: sails.js, swagger

I have a sailsjs API and I want to integrate it with swagger. I tried various npm packages which do the trick of generating the swagger.json confifg file. The problem is it generates swagger configs for ALL routes.

In my routes.js I have disabled some endpoints

```
  'GET /user': {response: 'notFound'},
  'POST /user': {response: 'notFound'},
  'PATCH /user': {response: 'notFound'},
  'PUT /user': {response: 'notFound'},
  'DELETE /user': {response: 'notFound'}
```

[image: swagger]

These are essentially disabled (autogenerated) endpoints, so I don't want them listed in my API documentation.

Every time I run my API the swagger doc is generated. The only other option I can think of is to manually curate my swagger doc.

I can ADD params to swagger for these by adding a swagger config block in the route definition, but I have not found any way to disable swagger for a specific endpoint by modifying the config.

Comment: maybe with a little more code and the module used to generate your doc we could help you more

Answer (score 0):

Try `deprecated: true` to ignore certain route operations in swagger. Swagger has various other operations to manipulate these paths - more info on [Deprecated Operations and other operations here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/).

Answer (score 0):

Insert as comment, inside the desired routes, the following line:

```
// #swagger.ignore = true
```